# ArgumentException: An HttpContext is required to perform this operation. Check that this operation is being performed during a web request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I was trying to access a class library from one of my applications and it was throwing the following exception:

```
> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the
> request.ArgumentException: An HttpContext is required to perform this
> operation. Check that this operation is being performed during a web
> request.System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetTokens(string
> oldCookieToken, out string newCookieToken, out string formToken) 
> Stack    Query    Cookies    Headers   ArgumentException: An
> HttpContext is required to perform this operation. Check that this
> operation is being performed during a web
> request.System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetTokens(string
> oldCookieToken, out string newCookieToken, out string formToken)
> Custom.Storage.Web.Common.Helpers.AntiCsrfHelper.GetProtectedStateAndCookieToken(AuthState
> state, out string cookieToken)
> Custom.AspNetCore.Storage.Areas.Storage.Controllers.StorageController+<>c__DisplayClass15_0+<<BeginAuthorizationAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> Custom.AspNetCore.Storage.Areas.Storage.Controllers.StorageController+<ProcessRequestWithProviderAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> Custom.AspNetCore.Storage.Areas.Storage.Controllers.StorageController+<BeginAuthorizationAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor+<CastToObject>d__38.MoveNext()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task
> task)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref
> State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref
> State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

My Startup.cs includes the `HttpContextAccessor` registration:

`services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

What could be the reason behind getting this issue. Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: There's not a lot of information to go on here. Try including the class that uses `IHttpContextAccessor`.

Comment: for downvoters: I know, sometimes it's hard to explain everything but downvoting neither solves the problem nor allows us improve much the way we ask question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   ArgumentException: An HttpContext is required to perform this
>   operation. Check that this operation is being performed during a web
>   request.
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetTokens(string oldCookieToken, out string newCookieToken, out string formToken)

You are using `System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetTokens` there (directly or indirectly). That is “classic” ASP.NET, as in `System.Web`, not ASP.NET Core. Classic ASP.NET used a lot of static objects, in this case it’s looking for [`System.Web.HttpContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx).

However, ASP.NET Core and the framework’s ASP.NET are incompatible. ASP.NET Core does not use the types in the `System.Web` namespace, so you cannot use *anything* that was built for ASP.NET with ASP.NET Core.

Fortunately, a lot of things are available with ASP.NET Core by default. If you’re looking for anti-request forgery, there’s something built-in for ASP.NET Core. Check out [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery) for more information on how to get it starting.

In general, make sure you’re using ASP.NET Core guides and packages. It can be a bit confusing, but there are already a lot of solutions for ASP.NET Core available.

Comment: You are right, previously we were passing an out argument and that could produce Token from AntiForgery.GetTokens(), which was failing in our case. So, instead of handling the token on the .net application, we added using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery; in our .net core project and now passing the tokens using current HttpContext from our .net core application to that .net application. I will provide the details and post as an answer.